# Python: I have a list and I want to add it to each element of the list

Tags: python, loops, integer

Let us take an example:
I have a list: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`
I want to add each element to be added with each other.
Such as `1+2, 1+3, 1+4, 1+5, 2+1, 2+3, 2+4, 2+5,` and so on.
So the output should come something like `3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6, 7` and so on.

Can anyone please help me solve this?

Comment: Show us your what you tried so far

Comment: Use a nested for loop and keep appending the added value to a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import starmap, permutations
from operator import add

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(list(starmap(add, permutations(values, 2))))
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `itertools.permutations`:

```
from itertools import permutations

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
new_list = [x+y for x,y in permutations(my_list, 2)]
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```py
def yar(int_list):

    har = []

    for num in int_list:
    
        fiddly = []
        
        for value in int_list:
            
            add = num
            
            add += value
            
            fiddly.append(add)
        
        har.append(fiddly)
    
    return har

fee = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(yar(fee))

# would output [[2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

The bread and butter to solving this is a nested `for` loop. For each number in the list (being `fee` in this case), loop through each number in the list `fee` and add it to the value in stored in `add` from the outer loop, then store that value in a list (that being `fidddly`).

I added the `har` list so users can access the combinations from each iteration. (index 0 for combos of 1, index 1 for combos of 2, etc.)

You can make this a list comprehension somehow, I'm sure of it for some reason. I'm just not the best at figuring that out yet, but this code still works.

Answer (score 0):

If all your elements are distinct, you can do it in a list comprehension than adds every number with all the numbers except itself:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

S = [ a+b for a in L for b in L if a!=b]

# [3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If there can be duplicate numbers in the list, then you need to exclude addition of numbers with themselves based on their indexes:

```
[ a+b for i,a in enumerate(L) for j,b in enumerate(L) if i!=j]
```